# Selenium with Python - Wait indefinitely until an input box is present

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want a WebDriver instance to monitor a page indefinitely until an input box appears with the name 'move.'  Once the input box appears, I want to fill it with some text and click a submit button adjacent to the form.  What is the easiest way to do this?

I have something like this now:

```
try:
    move = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "move"))
    )
finally:
    wd.quit()
```

And the button adjacent to the form has no name or id, so I am locating it by XPATH.  I want to wait until that form is present before click the button.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> monitor a page indefinitely until an input box appears

An [Explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) you've used in the example *requires a timeout value defined*. Either you set a very high value for the timeout, or it is not an option.

Alternatively, you can have a `while True` loop until an element would be found:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        form = driver.find_element_by_name("move")
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue

button = form.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::button")
button.click()
```

where I'm assuming the `button` element is a [following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) of the form.

Comment: you're absolutely brilliant.  I'm getting the following error with the button strategy: http://i.imgur.com/Ov9gjOx.png.  Any ideas?  And the HTML looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/hUwP8kc.png